# dynamic view of the syncfusion schedule angular component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, syncfusion

In the parameterization of the Schedule to Angular component I would like to know if it is possible to somehow define the start time and end time for a day.

I would like to define for each day what is the start time and the end time.

As this [example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.185276457.1675591703.1570470286-578596555.1563196694#/material/schedule/group-custom-work-days) I realized that the start time and end time is for every day, I would like to set the start time and end time for each day.

```
  const resourceObject = {
    text: p.nome, id: p.id,
    color: '#848484', workDays: daysNumber, 
     startHour: '13:00', endHour: '18:00'
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

We have prepared the below sample to have different work hours per day using DataBinding event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxqnrc-njutc8?file=app.component.ts

Please refer below UG.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/schedule/#setworkhours

```
if (this.flag) {
  if (
    this.scheduleObj.currentView !== "Month" &&
    this.scheduleObj.currentView !== "Agenda"
  ) {
    var currentViewDates = this.scheduleObj.getCurrentViewDates();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentViewDates.length; i++) {
      switch ((currentViewDates[i] as any).getDay()) {
        case 0:
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "06:00",
            "14:00"
          );
          break;
        case 1:
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "08:00",
            "14:00"
          );
          break;
        case 2:
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "07:00",
            "20:00"
          );
          break;
        case 3:
        debugger;
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "09:00",
            "13:00"
          );
          break;
        case 4:
        debugger
           this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "06:00",
            "14:00"
          );
          break;
        case 5:
        debugger
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "08:00",
            "15:00"
          );
          break;
        case 6:
          this.scheduleObj.setWorkHours(
            [currentViewDates[i]],
            "07:00",
            "19:00"
          );
      }
    }
  }
  this.flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is valid, but it does not apply to what I have developed which is as it is in the link. Because I have several professionals who serve different days and different times, the way you did it applies only to one professional.